# Using a plugin in struts.xml prevent to run application

Tags: java, struts2

In my struts2 web application for menus i am using struts menu plugin.I am using eclipse juno for my struts2 web application. When I write following plugin in my struts.xml it runs my project for some time but after some time it prevent my application to run.
My struts.xml as follows:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources" />

    <package name="default" extends="jasperreports-default,struts-default" namespace="/">

        <action name="login" 
            class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" >Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

     <plug-in className="net.sf.navigator.menu.MenuPlugIn">
        <set-property property="menuConfig" value="/WEB-INF/menu-config.xml"/>
     </plug-in>

</struts>
```

After that, if i cut that plugin code from my struts.xml and refresh my project and paste it again then it runs successfully for some time.After some time it again show error icon on my project. How can i resolved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write `<plug-in>` in struts.xml for struts2 web application.

> Struts 1 provides a plugin class that provides listener-like
> capabilities.
> The Struts 2 plugins are like Eclipse or FireFox plugins, and not at
> all like Struts 1 "plugins".
>
> A Struts 2 plugin is a single JAR that contains classes and
> configuration that extend, replace, or add to existing Struts
> framework functionality. A plugin can be installed by adding a JAR
> file to the application's class path, in addition to the JAR files to
> fulfill whatever dependencies the plugin itself may have. To configure
> the plugin, the JAR should contain a struts-plugin.xml file, which
> follows the same format as an ordinary struts.xml file.

Refer following link :
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/plugins.html